# PHP header not working in MAMP even after removing white space

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header, mamp

I am using MAMP and for some reason I am not getting redirected using header in php, can someone please have a look at the following code if there is something wrong in it???

I have read similar posts and found that it is caused by a sort of white space before header tag but in my case it is not.

Please give your advices...thanx

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 

$username="root"; // Mysql username 

$password="root"; // Mysql password 

$db_name="DBase"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="customers"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from the form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:/Account/index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Location: http://example.com/Account/index.php');
exit;
```

is one way to do this but you can use output buffering to get around this problem, with the overhead of all of your output to the browser being buffered in the server until you send it. You can do this by calling `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` in your script, or setting the output_buffering configuration directive on in your php.ini or server configuration files.

EDIT AND APPEND SOLUTION: ------>

You can use Output Buffering as

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 

$username="root"; // Mysql username 

$password="root"; // Mysql password 

$db_name="DBase"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="customers"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from the form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:/Account/index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password.";
}
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

The problem is that we cannot send the header after we start sending the output. To solve this we buffer the output. The function ob_start turns output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. So the echo output will be buffered. Next we send the header without any problem as we've not yet spit out any output. Finally we call ob_end_flush to flush the internal buffer contents and to stop output buffering.

Comment: is that possible to give an example in my script case, where exactly to use above functions???

Comment: This is great @Ziinloader - that ob_start(); function is what I needed to be compatible with MAMP.  Nice work!  and thanks for the detailed explanation - it really helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in MAMP and it turned out that output_buffering was disabled in my php.ini configuration file. All I had to do is turn it back on.

in php.ini find this line:

```
output_buffering = Off
```

and change it to:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

Then restart MAMP

Please see this post for more details:
http://hibbard.eu/php-headerlocation-not-working-in-mamp/

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/Account/index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: Yep, most browsers attempt to fix invalid `Location` headers, just like they fix invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks Vicario,
but I am using local server "MAMP".